# Design pattern to correctly deduct credit balance in parallel HTTP requests

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, software-design, accounting

To keep it simple, let say user can purchase prepaid credits from my website. Then user can make HTTP requests to my API service. Each HTTP request will cost 1 credit. I also have transaction log the request (like ledger) in a table and calculate the new balance credit and update the value in another table.

My problem is when user have balance credit of 1 and starts making multiple HTTP requests (parallel) at same time, my authorization policy in my server will simply accept all their requests since they have 1 credit balance left over at the time of making that request. Is there any design pattern or any solution that i can implement to avoid this kind of race condition?

I have thought about some solutions such as implementing a queue system and database row locking. But this all seems convoluted and with little experience in this area i think many can go wrong.

I am also ready to fully rewrite if there is solid design pattern or solution that solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I think there's 3 mains ways to approach this:

1. Strong consistency with multi-threading: you have to have a locking mechanism. Either Optimistic locking with retries or pessimistic locking. Since concurrency is expected here optimistic locking is probably a poor choice. The pessimistic lock could be at the application level or the DB level.
2. Inbox pattern (actor-model): single processing thread that processes messages in order from an inbox (queue).
3. Eventual consistency: detect violations and issue compensating actions. For instance, you'd detect overdrafts and charge penalties for exceeding the limit.

I'd probably go for #1 (pessimistic locking) here unless you have all the infrastructure required to implement #2 without implementing an inbox yourself, etc. Note that you wouldn't lock the entire execution of the HTTP request, just what needs to be synchronized.

Comment: Thanks plalx. I have looked up both solutions and done some research on it. The single processing queue seems will work for me. My plan is to trigger a webhook from queue if they have already exceeded the limit.